# Firebase multiple devices synchronization

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Need help with the following scenario with Firebase (I am not a developer):

Let say I have two devices: iPhone and iPad.

At 3 pm, both my devices are on network (i.e. they are not offline).

I  create a shopping list "Birthday" with no items, after login into iPhone App.

Then I login into my iPad, and I can see that there is a shopping list "Birthday" with no items.

At 3:30 pm my iPad goes offline.

At 3:35 pm, I login into my iPhone and then add an item "Cake" to my "Birthday" shopping list.

But as my iPad is offline, I don't see item "Cake" in my shopping list.

At 3:45 pm, using my iPad which is offline, I add an item "Candles" to my shopping list.

Now, when I login into my iPhone, I see only one item "Cake" in my shopping list.

Now at 4:00 pm, my iPad is on the network (i.e. it is not offline any more). So it synchronizes with Firebase.

So now at 4:10 pm, when I login into the iPhone App, then what I am going to see:
Option 1. Only Candles: as iPad app overwrote the shopping list.
Option 2. Cake and Candles both, in the order Cake, then Candles
Option 3. Candles and Cake both, in the order Candles and then Cake.

I am looking for the Option 3, Is it possible to do it? Is it possible to get the list from Firebase database, then modify to add the item on top of the list?

-- Thanks David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how you implement this. But if you use Firebase's `push()` method to add items, they'll get IDs that are guaranteed to be unique and chronological, regardless of whether you're online or offline. This means they show up in the order they were added: Cake, Candles.

Comment: Thanks Frank it helps. The second part of question is that when Cake was added, as part of the schema, there is an item order also. So  it means Cake and 1. So item order means it will be first item in the list to be displayed. Now iPad device, will have Candles and 1. So as per your reply after synchronization, it will be Cake 1 and Candles 1. So Is it possible that when the iPad was on network then when synchronization happened, then developer can write a code to change the order of Candles to 2 when it sees that Cake is already present, so that in Firebase: Cake 1, Candles 2.

Comment: If you call `push()` then the order will be chronological (for the most part) even when the clients are not connected to the server. If you define your own indexing mechanism, then you will have to find your own way to prevent overlap in indexes. But since Firebase's push IDs were precisely created to solve this problem, I don't know why you wouldn't use them here.

Comment: Thanks Frank for your quick response.